# On a certain integral related to Euler-Masheroni constant

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-number-theory, euler-mascheroni-constant

When trying to derive Mertens' theorem using Perron's formula, I encountered the following integral:

$$
\int_0^1{1-e^{-t}\over t}\mathrm dt-\int_1^\infty{e^{-t}\over t}\mathrm dt
$$

which, according to Titchmarsh's *The Theory of Riemann Zeta Function*, evaluates to $\gamma$ (a.k.a. Euler-Mascheroni constant).

To begin with, I converted this integral into the following limit:

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\int_0^1{1-(1-t/N)^N\over t}\mathrm dt-\int_1^N{(1-t/N)^N\over t}\mathrm dt\right]
$$

so that I can eventually simplify the expression into

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{m=1}^N\frac1m-\log N\right]
$$

which is identical to the definition of $\gamma$.

I wonder what tools can be used to justify the limit step.

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem in both cases.

Comment: @Surb Thanks, that works for me :D

Comment: I follow exactly this way [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3794399).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

To show that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_1^N \frac{\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N}{t}\,dt=\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt$$

we will show that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_1^N \frac{e^{-t}}t \left(e^t\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N-1\right)\,dt=0\tag 1$$

Proceeding, we use the inequalities

$$\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N\le e^{-t}\tag 2$$

and

$$\begin{align}
e^t\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N &\ge \left(1+\frac tN\right)^N\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N\\\\
&=\left(1-\frac{t^2}{N^2}\right)^N\\\\
&\ge 1-\frac{t^2}{N}\tag3
\end{align}$$

Using $(2)$ and $(3)$, we have the estimates for the integral in $(1)$

$$-\frac1N \int_1^N te^{-t}\,dt \le \int_1^N \frac{e^{-t}}t \left(e^t\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N-1\right)\,dt\le 0\tag4$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem to $(4)$ yields $(1)$.

---

To show that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{1-\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N}{t}\,dt=\int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\,dt$$

we exploit the uniform convergence of $\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N$ to $e^{-t}$ for $t\in [0,1]$.  Then, we may interchange the limit and integral to obtain the result.

---

Putting it together, we have

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\int_1^N \frac{\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N}{t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{1-\left(1-\frac tN\right)^N}{t}\,dt\right)=\int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\,dt-\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt$$

as was to be shown.

---

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

There is another way to proceed.  We can write the integral of interest as

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\,dt-\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_\varepsilon^1  \frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}\,dt-\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_1^L \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt\tag1
\end{align}$$

Integrating by parts both of the integrals on the right-hand side of $(1)$ we find

$$\begin{align}
I&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(-(1-e^{-\varepsilon})\log(\varepsilon)-\int_\varepsilon^1  e^{-t}\log(t)\,dt\right)\\\\
&-\lim_{L\to \infty}\left(e^{-L}\log(L)-\int_1^L e^{-t}\log(t)\,dt\right)\\\\
&=-\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\log(t)\,dt\\\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, using the development in the NOTE section of [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100567/real-analysis-methodologies-to-show-gamma-2-int-0-infty-frac-cosx2-cos/2101763#2101763), we see that $-\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\log(t)\,dt=\gamma$ as was to be shown!

Comment: This presumes that one knows the final integral representation. But the OP's definition is in terms of a limit, so converting from one integral representation to another doesn't exactly seem like progress.

Comment: @Semiclassical The resulting integral representation herein is a standard representation.  In fact, in the "NOTE" section of [THIS ANSWER}(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100567/real-analysis-methodologies-to-show-gamma-2-int-0-infty-frac-cosx2-cos/2101763#2101763), I showed that it is equal to the limit definition in the OP.

Comment: @Semiclassical I've edited to address the OP's question and kept, as a second approach, my initial answer.  ;-)

Comment: Well, the second method is what I was trying to avoid since I am writing an article about this for my classmates and do not want to get too much into Gamma function. Still, +1 for your elegant first method :D